# Training and Testing Data set for classification text file

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

Suppose we have 10000 text file and We would like to classify as political ,health,weather,sports,Science ,Education,.........
I need training data set for classification of text documents and I am Naive  Bayes classification Algorithm. Anyone can help to get data sets .
OR
Is there any another way to get classification done..I am new at Machine Learning Please explain your answer completely.

Example:

```
     **Sentence**                                         **Output**
```

1) Obama won  election. ----------------------------------------------->political

2) India won by 10 wickets ---------------------------------------------->sports

3) Tobacco is more dangerous --------------------------------------------->Health

4) Newtons laws of motion can be applied to car -------------->science

Any way to classify these sentences into their respective categories

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to google it? There are tons and tons of datasets for text categorization. The classical one is Reuters-21578 (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Reuters-21578+Text+Categorization+Collection), another famous one and mentioned almost in each ML book is 20 newsgroup: http://web.ist.utl.pt/acardoso/datasets/

But there are lots of other, one google query away from you. Just load them, slightly adjust if needed and train your classifier on that datasets.

Comment: I have downloaded both Reuters and 20 newsgroup . but my problem is I am not getting how to use them in my system.  My naive bayes classifier take input as

Comment: I have downloaded both Reuters and 20 newsgroup . but my problem is I am not getting how to use them in my system.  My naive bayes classifier take input as                                                                                                      trainingFiles.put(Classifier_NAME, NaiveBayesExample.class.getResource( Filename_HERE));

Comment: Okay -- what happened when you used one of the files you found to train a model?  You already have the file name; choose the classifier you want, specify that, and make the call.

Comment: hello prune, basically is working but as weak classifier

Comment: Crime news classified as Entertainment . So I want data set which covers all kinds of news categories which varies from political to health